# Integrating FastAPI with graphene Graphql

Tags: python, graphql, fastapi, graphene-python

```
from starlette_graphene3 import GraphQLApp
from graphene import Schema, Int, String, List, ObjectType
from fastapi import FastAPI


class Query(ObjectType):
    hello = String(name=String(default_value="World"))

    def resolve_hello(self, info, name):
        return 'Hello ' + name


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def home():
    return {
        "message": "Hello you may consider going to /graphql."
    }


schema = Schema(query=Query)
app.mount("/", GraphQLApp(schema=schema))
```

The code above are running without error but if I try to access the page from browser this is the output.
[image]

The console results after accessing that `graphql` route is
[image]

How can I solve this issue. Please I need your help. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to hit `/graphql` endpoint, you should mount as follows:

```
app.mount("/graphql", GraphQLApp(schema=schema))
```

The first parameter in `mount()` accepts the route on which to serve the GraphQLApp on.